# input field submit issue, all fields submit to the database except one

Tags: php, html, input

I went live with my website about 3 days ago and we are running into an issue which I cannot figure out for the life of me. My website is www.bookling.co and when the user tries to edit their profile there are 10 fields, business name, name, specialty, about me, email, website, facebook, twitter, pintrest, and google plus. I have 114 registered users and for a handful of them the about me section will not insert into the database. It works for me every time, but for some of my users it doesnt. I have tried it on multiple browsers and on different computers and it always works for me, i even created multiple profiles and still worked. I need help figuring out why it will work for some but not for others. Here is the code for the input field:

```
<?php
header('Location: userprofile.php');
define('QUADODO_IN_SYSTEM', true);
require_once('includes/header.php');
include_once('includes/mysqli_connection.php');
$qls->Security->check_auth_page('members.php');




//
$business_name=$_POST['business_name'];
$name=$_POST['name'];
$about_me=$_POST['about_me'];
$specialty=$_POST['specialty'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$website=$_POST['website'];
$facebook=$_POST['facebook'];
$twitter=$_POST['twitter'];
$pintrest=$_POST['pintrest'];
$googleplus=$_POST['googleplus'];



// Insert data into mysql 
$id=$qls->user_info['id'];
$sql="UPDATE qls3_users SET business_name='$business_name', name='$name', about_me='$about_me', specialty='$specialty', email='$email', website='$website', facebook='$facebook', twitter='$twitter', pintrest='$pintrest', googleplus='$googleplus' WHERE id='$id'";
$result=mysqli_query($db_conx,$sql);
?>

<?php 
// close connection 
mysqli_close('$db_conx');
?>

<!-- Edit Profile Modal -->
                <!-- Button trigger modal -->
                <button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Edit Profile</button>
                <?php include_once( 'modals/profile_img.php');?>
                <!--Edit Profile Modal -->
                <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit Profile</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <form action="edit_profile.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="eprofile" onsubmit="return checkRequired2();">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" name="business_name" placeholder="Business Name" value="<?php echo $qls->user_info['business_name'];?>">
                                    <br>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" name="name" placeholder="Name" value="<?php echo $qls->user_info['name'];?>">
                                    <br>
                                    <textarea class="form-control" name="about_me" rows="3" maxlength="535" lengthcut="true" placeholder="About Me"><?php echo $qls->user_info['about_me'];?></textarea>
                                    <br>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail" placeholder="My Specialties" name="specialty" value="<?php echo $qls->user_info['specialty'];?>">
                                    <br>
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail" placeholder="Email" name="email" value="<?php echo $qls->user_info['email'];?>">
                                    <br>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail" placeholder="Website" name="website" value="<?= $qls->user_info['website'];?>">
                                    <br>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail" name="facebook" placeholder="Facebook Link" value="<?php echo $qls->user_info['facebook'];?>">
                                    <br>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail" name="twitter" placeholder="Twitter Link" value="<?php echo $qls->user_info['twitter'];?>">
                                    <br>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail" name="pintrest" placeholder="Pintrest Link" value="<?php echo $qls->user_info['pintrest'];?>">
                                    <br>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail" name="googleplus" placeholder="Google+ Link" value="<?php echo $qls->user_info['googleplus'];?>">
                                    <br>
                                    <div class="note">*Potential clients will be able to view your profile, make sure to use as much information as possible to gain their interests.</div>
                                    <br>
                                    <br>
                                    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="submit">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                </form>
                                <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/assets/js/charcount.js"></script>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Just because it irks me: Your button should say `Search Photographers`, not `Search Photographer's`—no apostrophe!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$business_name = $db_conx->real_escape_string($_POST['business_name']);
$name = $db_conx->real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$about_me = $db_conx->real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['about_me'], ENT_QUOTES));
$specialty = $db_conx->real_escape_string($_POST['specialty']);
$email = $db_conx->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$website = $db_conx->real_escape_string($_POST['website']);
$facebook = $db_conx->real_escape_string($_POST['facebook']);
$twitter = $db_conx->real_escape_string($_POST['twitter']);
$pintrest = $db_conx->real_escape_string($_POST['pintrest']);
$googleplus = $db_conx->real_escape_string($_POST['googleplus']);
```